# Append data to the next row of a table in a forEach loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to append data to the next row of a table (That starts out blank) in html and I can't seem to get it to work.

Here is the function I have for when a button is pressed to update the table with the current data. I get an error in the console that says forEach is not a function. Can someone give me more information about why this is happening?

```
//Updates the table when the update button is pressed
function updateButton(){
        function updateButton(){
    $.get( "Some PHP server data", function( data ) {
        data.forEach(function(row) {
            var htmltext = "<tr><td>"+row.lastname+"</td><td>"+row.currentcity+"</td><td>"+row.uid+"</td><td>"+row.ip+"</td><td>"+row.updateTime+"</td></tr>"

            $(("#table1").find('tbody').append($(htmltext)));
        });
    });

}
```

Here is the html I have for the table element.

```
<table id="table1" class="table table-striped">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Current City</th>
    <th>uid</th>
    <th>IP</th>
    <th>When</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You are missing a `+` sign right after `"<td>".

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't work when I fix it.

Comment: Save the entire thing as a single string in a variable, then append the html string.

Comment: You forget close `</tr>` in `.append($("<td>"+row.lastname+"</td>"+"<td>"+row.currentcity+"</td>"+"<td>"+row.uid+"</td>"+"<td>"+row.ip+"</td>"+"<td>"+row.updateTime+"</td></tr>")`

Comment: What is `data = $.load("some url")` supposed to do? I can't find this function.

Comment: That is not how jQuery load works.... Why are you doing that inside a get call?

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: Yea, you're right. I get an error that says Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list, that is on the last line of the function

Comment: Edited the post a bit

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use `$("#table1 tbody")` instead of `find`?

Comment: No, I just tried that, and still get the error with the forEach loop

Answer (score 0):

This should be slightly more straight forward.

```
var html = "<tr><td>"+row.lastname+"</td><td>"+row.currentcity+"</td><td>"+row.uid+"</td><td>"+row.ip+"</td><td>"+row.updateTime+"</td></tr>"

$("#table1").find('tbody').append(html);
```

Comment: Yea, not sure why I didn't think of this. I edited the post

Comment: Take the $ off.  Just use `append(html)`. Also, check the documentation of `forEach`  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forEach.asp

Answer (score 0):

I removed your "database" stuff because I cant test your connection to your database. I merely left the necessary HTML and JavaScript side of things.

Just click the "button" to add a row to your table in the linked jsFiddle.

Here's the HTML.

```
<div id="button">
  Press to add row
</div>

<table id="table1" class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Current City</th>
      <th>uid</th>
      <th>IP</th>
      <th>When</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbody">

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's the JavaScript.

```
function updateButton() {

  $("#table1").find("tBody").append($("<tr><td>"+ "row.firstname" + "</td>" + "<td>" +"rowLastName" + "</td>" + "<td>" + "row.currentcity" + "</td>" + "<td>" + "row.uid" + "</td>" + "<td>" + "row.ip" + "</td>" + "<td>" + "row.updateTime" + "</td> </tr>"));
}

var button = document.getElementById('button');
button.onclick = function() {
  updateButton();
}
```

And here's a jsFiddle. Hope this helps.

https://jsfiddle.net/1qutvgrp/1/

As for your forEach question... 
An example below:

```
var targetList = [];
var selectedFilters = $(SelectedItems()); // An array of items
selectedFilters.each(function (index, listitem)
{
    var temp = _objectList[$(listitem)[0].getAttribute('hash')];
    targetList.push(temp);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this was pretty helpful, but I ran into another problem. I edited the post

Comment: You can make use of jQuery .each() method. Example in my post.

https://api.jquery.com/each/